# Faster 2D array generation

Tags: python, numpy

I would like a faster way to generate a 2D array in Python using NumPy. My code uses a generator:

```
h,w= img.shape[:2]
points= [[x-w/2,y-h/2,img[y,x]] for y in range(h) for x in range(w) if img[y,x]!=0]
```

How can I make this faster with Numpy? `img` is a 10x10 2D numpy.array. The code is not slow, however I need to repeat this 336 times.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include example input data (no undefined variables in your code) and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up example data:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
img = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
h,w= img.shape
points= [[x-w/2,y-h/2,img[y,x]] for y in range(h) for x in range(w) if img[y,x]!=0]
points = np.array(points)
```

With NumPy:

```
np_points = np.vstack([np.where(img != 0), img[img != 0].ravel()]).T[:,[1,0,2]] - [w/2 , h/2, 0]
assert np.array_equal(np_points,points), 'solutions are not equal'
```

Not a huge difference. The NumPy solution would benefit from vectorized computation of all images at once.

```
%%timeit
for i in range(336):
  np_points = np.vstack([np.where(img != 0), img[img != 0].ravel()]).T[:,[1,0,2]] - [w/2 , h/2, 0]
```

Out:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 7.71 ms per loop
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(336):
  points= [[x-w/2,y-h/2,img[y,x]] for y in range(h) for x in range(w) if img[y,x]!=0]
```

Out:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 25.6 ms per loop
```